# What is the chance of rolling a 7 on two weighted die?

Tags: probability, dice

Say one die is weighted to land on $6$ and the other is weighted to land on the $1$, and a die is four times more likely to land on the weighted side compared to a non-weighted side. What is the probability of the $2$ die summing to seven?

Thought Process:
The probability of a die landing on the weighted side is $4/9$. So the probability of both dice landing on the weighted side is $16/81$.

What I'm struggling with is the fact that there is still a chance for the dice to land on some other side, and still sum up to seven. I don't know how to find the total probability.

Comment: How would you compute the probability in an unweighted die?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It would be simply 1/6, because the first roll doesn't really matter, as there is exactly one number on the 2nd die for each number on the first die that sums to 7.

Comment: @CoderTang wow! that's a great perspective too.

Comment: So... you found the 16/81 to be if the "one-heavy" first die lands on 1 and the "six-heavy" second die lands on six.  Can you find the probability for the first die to land on 2 and the second die to land on five?  How about 3 and 4... 4 and 3?  5 and 2?  6 and 1?  What do you suppose we should do with all of these?  Have you finished the problem now as a result?

Comment: @JMoravitz I believe it would be 1/81, because there is a 1/9 chance to land on each non-weighted side. Should I just add the probabilities for each of the other sides?

Comment: Note that the answer of 1/6 for fair dice, if you were to roll the dice in sequence or color them red and blue or however else... we have $\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{36}$... which could be explained as rolling a 1 and 6, or a 2 and 5, or a 3 and 4, or a 4 and 3 etc...

Comment: @JMoravitz So would it be 16/81 + 5(1/81)?

Comment: Yes... that's all there was to it

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the weighted die, the probability is $\frac{4}{9}$ of landing on the weighted side, and $\frac{1}{9}$ of landing on any of the other 5 sides.  With two dice, there are 6 combinations that add to 7.  (I've put the weighted sides in bold.)

- (1, 6) = (1/9)(1/9) = 1/81
- (2, 5) = (1/9)(1/9) = 1/81
- (3, 4) = (1/9)(1/9) = 1/81
- (4, 3) = (1/9)(1/9) = 1/81
- (5, 2) = (1/9)(1/9) = 1/81
- (**6**, **1**) = (**4/9**)(**4/9**) = 16/81

So the total probability is $\frac{16}{81} + 5(\frac{1}{81}) = \frac{21}{81} = \frac{7}{27}$.